# `make` does not work on `dbus-glib-0.104`

Tags: xfce, make, dbus, glib

My system is Ubuntu 14.10, I used `make` on other packages minutes before this, so in general it is working.

My aim is to install `xfce4-windowck-plugin-0.2.4` for which I am trying to manually solve the dependencies.

The current folder contains everything I extracted from here: http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus-glib/dbus-glib-0.104.tar.gz

I get the following output from running `make` after successfully running `./configure --prefix=/usr`

```
bytecommander@AlkaliMetal:~/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104'
Making all in dbus
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus'
Making all in examples
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
Making all in .
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
  CCLD     example-client
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_no_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_path@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_list_registered@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_enabled@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_recurse@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_get_interval@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get_private@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_steal_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_threads_init_default@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_args@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_add_filter@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_dispatch@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_is_signal@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_member@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_wakeup_main_function@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_handle@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_get_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_no_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_remove_match@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_get_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_block@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_handle@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new_method_return@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_try_register_object_path@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_set_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send_with_reply@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_signature_iter_recurse@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_sender@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_next@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_add_match@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_signature@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_server_allocate_data_slot@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_set_error_from_message@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_flags@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unregister_object_path@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_get_object_path_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_ref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_init_append@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new_signal@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_error_free@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_signature_iter_get_current_type@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_path@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_signature_iter_init@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_cancel@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_free@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_is_method_call@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_server_get_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_set_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_init@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_open_private@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_timeout_get_enabled@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_data@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_close_container@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_watch_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_watch_get_unix_fd@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_timeout_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_get_dispatch_status@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_server_set_watch_functions@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_fixed_array@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_remove_filter@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_interface@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_free_data_slot@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_abandon_container@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_signature@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_get_interface@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_set_notify@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_append_basic@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_flush@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_open_container@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_append_args@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_get_basic@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_error_init@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new_error@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_free_string_array@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_new_method_call@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_iter_append_fixed_array@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_ref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_set_error@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_message_set_destination@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_pending_call_unref@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_open@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_signature_iter_next@LIBDBUS_1_3'
../../dbus/.libs/libdbus-glib-1.so: undefined reference to `dbus_connection_allocate_data_slot@LIBDBUS_1_3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:436: recipe for target 'example-client' failed
make[5]: *** [example-client] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
Makefile:496: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
Makefile:391: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus/examples'
Makefile:1009: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104/dbus'
Makefile:512: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bytecommander/Downloads/xfce-deb/dbus-glib-0.104'
Makefile:411: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install its missing dependencies first, which are, according to [Linuxfromscratch.org: dbus-glib-0.104](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/dbus-glib.html):

- [`D-Bus-1.8.6`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/dbus.html)
- [`GLib-2.42.2`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/glib2.html)

`D-Bus` in `Utopic` (package `dbus`) is listed as version `1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1`;

`GLib` in `Utopic` (package `glib2.0`) is listed as version `2.42.1-1~ubuntu1`;

So you can update `D-Bus` via `apt`:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dbus`

But you'll have to download and to install `GLib-2.42.2` manually after having resolved all of its dependencies: [Gnome.org: GLib Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/)

Another option would be to install a later version of `xfce4-windowck-plugin` (`0.3.0`) which is available on this `PPA` and listed as `xfce4-windowck-plugin`: `ppa:eugenesan/ppa`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xfce4-windowck-plugin
```

Comment: I thought I had those ones installed manually with make before as they appeared in the `./configure` output as missing. But `glib-config` seems not to exist. Can I `apt-get install` them (package name?) or do I have to download and `make` them too?

Comment: Will `Python 2.7.8` also work? That one is already installed.

Comment: @ByteCommander No, if they were missing they didn't got installed, since if `dbus-glib` came shipped with them ready to be installed they wouldn't have been dependencies, right? I don't think you can install specific versions from `apt-get`, unless you find some repository which provides such packages. `Python-2.7.8` should be ok.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am installing those things currently and already feel like never using `make` again... :P

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm sorry, I misread the `Python` version you were mentioning and I tought that it was a later version, while it's an earlier one. The point it's the following: I'm not sure that the site from which I pulled the informations from does mention the actual minimum version for each dependency or if it just links to the latest version in his site, so to be sure I'd rather install what it address as the required version, after all it shouldn't hurt. So I'd go with installing `Python-2.7.9`

Comment: Couldn't at least that one be in the repos?

Comment: Aargh! Python 2.7.9 does not `make install`: [...] Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xmllib.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py ...
Compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py ...
Makefile:1003: recipe for target 'libinstall' failed
make: *** [libinstall] Error 1

Comment: @ByteCommander Ok, to summarize: `D-Bus` on `Trusty` (package `dbus`) is listed as version `1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3`, `GLib-2.42.2` on `Trusty` (package `glib2.0`) is listed as version `2.40.2-0ubuntu1`, `libffi` on `Trusty` (package `libffi`) is listed as version `3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12`, and the same goes for `Python2` and `Python3`, so it looks like you'll have to install them manually checking for each dependency! Let me see if i can find a reliable source for the dependencies of `dbus-glib-0.104`

Comment: I have 14.10 (Utopic)

Comment: Turns out `dbus-glib` is in the repositories, listed as `libdbus-glib-1-2`, but the latest version for `Utopic` is listed as `0.102-1`. I'm unable to check if that's enough for installing `xfce4-windowck-plugin`, where did you pull `dbus-glib-0.104` from? Also for `Utopic` `dbus` version is listed as `1.8.8-1ubuntu2.1` but `glib2.0` is listed as `2.42.1-1~ubuntu1`, `python2.7` is listed as version `2.7.8-10ubuntu1` and `python3.4` is listed as version `3.4.2-1`

Comment: Link to dbus-glib-0.104 is in my Question. I also had the same error as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/597879/367990) in my make output of Python.

Comment: Apt-get installing `libdbus-glib-1-2` tells me it is already the latest version.

Comment: @ByteCommander What i meant is that you're manually trying to resolve the dependencies for `xfce4-windowck-plugin-0.2.4`, but where did you pull its dependencies from?

Comment: Mainly http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.10/src/ and http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/

Comment: @ByteCommander What I meant was: is there a reliable list of dependencies for it? Maybe you just need an earlier version of `dbus-glib`. If not you'll have to resolve all dependencies via `apt-get install` when possible (i.e. when the required version is present in the repositories for `Utopic`) or manually by building them with `make`

Comment: I got the archive to make the windowck-plugin, ran `./configure` and got a message that package xxx is missing. I downloaded the archive for that and `make` it as well. And solve that ones dependencies in the same way... I manually installed dbus-1.8.16.tar.gz
dbus-1.9.14.tar.gz
dbus-glib-0.104.tar.gz
glib-2.42.2.tar.xz
libffi-3.2.1.tar.gz
libxfce4ui-4.10.0.tar.bz2
libxfce4util-4.10.0.tar.bz2
Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
xfce4-dev-tools-4.10.0.tar.bz2
xfce4-windowck-plugin-0.2.4.tar.gz
xfconf-4.10.0.tar.bz2 or at least downloaded it and tried to.

Comment: @ByteCommander If you don't mind installing version `0.3.0` of the plugin instead, I found a `PPA` containing it, and that would allow you to not go through installing all such infinite list of dependencies

Comment: No, as long it's working, I'm fine. Please tell me. And what would I do with those infinite dependencies I already more or less installed?

Comment: @ByteCommander I suggest you to remove them with `make uninstall` before trying to install everything with the `PPA`, so that you can return to a clean state of the system before doing anything else. The `PPA` is `ppa:eugenesan/ppa` and the package is listed as `xfce4-windowck-plugin`, let me know if that worked so that i can update my answer

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you! I finally could install it. If I knew there would exist a PPA before starting to struggle with `make`... Anyway, I'm very happy that you helped me. The plugin is just working a little bit different as I expected: It put a maximised window's title and system buttons into the panel. I assumed, it would also remove the window's title bar then, but it does not seem to do so... You don't know that plugin, do you?

Comment: @ByteCommander Glad that it helped, nope i don't, anyway if it works at least as a temporary solution you can either wait for the required packages to update on the official repository (hopefully until June) or check carefully which dependencies are required for each branch (if you want to spend some time on it) in order to install the previous version. I'll update my answer to include that solution

Comment: No, I leave it like this. I found a tool on the web (maximus, installable from ppa) that adds the functionality to remove the window title bar when it's maximised. It works correctly, that addon is always needed.