# Missing bits for some modules during installation

Tags: 14.04, python

I install Python 2.7.9 from compiling its source on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.
Running `make` seems without error, but it also says that

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl
_tkinter           bsddb185           bz2
dbm                dl                 gdbm
imageop            readline           sunaudiodev
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

1. If I don't need the modules, can I safely ignore those modules and their missing bits for now? If I need the modules in the future, can I install them then?
2. If I need to install them, how shall I install the missing bits for the modules and then install the modules?

   - It says to look in [detect_modules()](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/python2.7.9/detect_modules.py)(I extract the function from setup.py into the linked file) in [setup.py](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/python2.7.9/setup.py) for the modules, but I am not sure how to do that for each module individually?
   - Are "the missing bits" some development libraries (not just shared libraries, but also having source code)? In Synaptic package manager, I am only guessing which library to install.

   For example,

   for `_ssl` module in python, shall I install `libssl-dev` in Ubuntu?

   for `_bsddb` and for `bsddb185`, I don't know what to install. In synaptic, `python-bsddb3` is already installed, and I don't find `libbsddb3-dev` or `libbsddb3`  but I find `python-bsddb3-dbg`. After installing `python-bsddb3-dbg`, `make` still says the bits for _bsddb`and for`bsddb185` not found.

   for `dl`, I found that in detect_modules(), it seems to require `dlfcn.h`, which seems to be part of POSIX. Since Linux is POSIX compatible, I was buffled by that Ubuntu has missing bits of `dl`.

   For `dbm` and `gdbm`, I find `libgdbm-dev` in synaptic, but no `libdbm` or `libdbm-dev` but only `libdbm-ocaml, libdbm-ocaml-dev, libdbm-deep-perl`. What shall I install then (especially for `dbm`)?

   For `sunaudiodev`, I find from detect_modules(), that it seems to be a SunOS specific module. But why I need it on Ubuntu then?
   Thanks.

   For `imageop`, detect_modules mentiones `imageop.c`, but I don't know how to find it to install either.

   For `_tkinter`, I have installed `python-tk` and `python-tk-dbg`, but `make` still says its bits not found.

---

After install some development libraries, now `make` reports bits of the following modules not found:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _tkinter           bsddb185        
dl                 imageop            sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

Comment: Old thread but I got stuck in a similar predicament for python3.7.0
I installed: build-essential checkinstall libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev wget liblzma-dev uuid-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses*-dev libbz2-dev;
and have narrowed it down to just one missing now _dbm.
I'm using gcc8.2 with enabled optimizations and lto

Comment: @DanglingPointer and Tim, why not just install all build dependent used by Ubuntu package using `sudo apt-get builddep python` or if you want see only missing dependency `sudo apt-get -s builddep python`

Comment: Facing similar issue.

Comment: Very similar to @DanglingPointer, python 3.8 was installed using: sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget, visit https://askubuntu.com/a/1261929/1107236 for more info.